# Use of multiagent parameter in the configuration of Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

What is the purpose of the multiagent parameter in the configuration of the Cygnus component?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cygnus documentation](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_docker/index.html#using-a-specific-configuration) is an option available in docker-based deployments, which purpose is as follows:

> Enable multiagent cygnus: CYGNUS_MULTIAGENT environment variable. If enabled, each sink will run in a diferent port

So it seems to be a way of executing different sinks (MySQL, CKAN, HDFS, etc.) using the same docker container.

Comment: Internally I'm not sure how many Cygnus instances are being used inside the docker container. It could be just one or one per sink (I tend to think the later, given that each sink is associated to a different port). It would be easy to check just looking inside the docker container once started. Anyway, from a end user perspective it doesn't matter as the magic happens internally in the docker container.